# Cannot redeem bounty

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have about 25K of bounty vouchers but I cannot seem to redeem them. I believe I am sitting in the proper station and it has a office to redeem claimed bounties.

```
Bounty: 25,380 CR BOUNTY IN INDEPENDENT ERAVATE FREE

STATION: CLEVE HUB / INDEPENDENT ERAVATE NETWORK
```

If I am in the wrong station how do I find the information needed to travel to the correct station. Where can i see the faction running the station prior to flying there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're in the right *system* to claim that bounty, but in the wrong *station*. "Independent Eravate Free" and "Eravate Network" are *not* the same thing.

There are two ways to find that info:

1. In the "Navigation" tab of the contacts (left) panel, select a station and 
   "lock destination". Now the left lower area of your front cockpit view 
   (to the right when viewing contacts panel) there's a very brief bit of info 
   about that station, including the controlling faction.
2. In the "Navigation" tab of the same panel you see the bounty in,
   there's a "System Map". Open that up and click on the different
   stations, looking for one controlled by the correct faction. You can
   also get to that information from the galaxy map and clicking the system
   information button (a tiny solar system/concentric circles).

From looking at that info from the galaxy/system map, I can see that you need to be in "Ackerman Market", "Sylvester City", or "Maine Hub" to claim a bounty from "Independent Eravate Free", since they (currently) control those 3 stations.

Note: in the "Status" tab of the System (right) panel, you can see what factions are present in a system, and what allegiance they each have. This can be useful if you have a bounty with a major faction, to find a station controlled by a local faction that's part of that major faction.

Side note: from the galaxy/system view, I see "Eravate Network" without "Independent" in the name. When you're in a station, it shows both the controlling faction and their allegiance (Federation, Empire, Alliance or Independent); maybe the "Independent" is actually the (lack of) allegiance to a major faction?

Comment: Pretty sure you're right about Independent being represented by a lack of major faction designation. I've noticed this as well.